# Is it possible to show grep output of +/- 3 words of the search keyword?

Tags: linux, grep

I want to store information in a text file and use grep to search.
With the command `grep -in <keyword> <file>`, I can show the line number and the line contains the keyword. However, the output will be sometime less readable if the line contains a long line of text.

Is it possible to show the grep command output with +/- 3 words of the search result instead of the whole line?

I am trying to get the result like
`$grep -in linux grep_test.txt`
1: A **Linux**-based system is a
1: monolithic kernel, the Linux kernel, which handles
3: part of most **Linux**-based systems, providing
3: used by most **Linux** systems is built
3: More recently, the **Linux** community seeks to

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use this test file:

```
$ cat file
a cat
a is for a cat and b is for bat
aa bb cat
cat in hat
```

And, let's use this regex to get up to three words before and after:

```
$ grep -inoE '(\w+\W+){0,3}cat(\W+\w+){0,3}' file
1:a cat
2:is for a cat and b is
3:aa bb cat
4:cat in hat
```

The option `-o` tells grep to show *only* the matching part.

In the regular expressions, `\w` means word characters and `\W` mean any character that is not a word character.  `{0,3}` matches zero to three of the pattern that it follows.  Because grep regexes are, by default, greedy, it will try to match as many of those three words as it can.

#### Controlling the highlighting

To highlight only the search word, `cat` in this case, use two greps:

```
grep -inoE '(\w+\W+){0,3}cat(\W+\w+){0,3}' file | grep -i cat
```

Because the first grep is sending its output to a pipeline, it does no highlighting.  The second grep, by contrast, does send its output to a terminal, so it is used to highlight whatever we want to highlight.

The above assumes that you have, as is very common, `grep --color=auto` as an alias to grep.  This tells `grep` to apply color when the output is going to a terminal but not if the output goes to a file or pipe.

If you don't have `--color=auto`, then you may turn color on explicitly for the last `grep`:

```
grep -inoE '(\w+\W+){0,3}cat(\W+\w+){0,3}' file | grep -i --color cat
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! With the `-inoE`, I could get the result I wanted, however, the output highlight everything that matches the regex specified. is it possible to highlight only the specific keyword and leave the +/3 words normal?

Comment: @code-ing OK.  I added code for that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. How could I not think of that.. grep it again :)

Comment: I edited the parameter on the second grep call to make the output closer to the requested format; highlighting just the search term.

Comment: @RichTBreak Thank you for pointing that out.  I have added to the answer some discussion of grep and color outputs.